# Modelling state with variables

Tags: r, regression, python, state-space-models, predictor

I have some absence data of some employee, associated to some characteristics (e.g. type: short, middle, long; people characteristic: gender, age, tenure… ; other variable like event dates etc. All these variables are at a daily level, but they could be concatenate at other level, like state (i.e. one observation won't be a day, but it would be a state with some added variable like for example the number of days in this state etc).

My goal is to find which variables is significantly explaining the absence. Also, some variable might explain short term absence, but not long term absence. For this reason, I thought not to create a model on daily level, but on 'healthy-sick state' level. More specifically, I would need to know the effect of the variable when passing from healthy(0) to short term absence (1), from healthy(0)  to middle term absence (2) and healthy(0)  to long term absence (3). But, a regression on the 0, 1, 2, 3 states won't give what I need, is it would look at this: from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, 3 to 4 instead of 0 to 1, 0 to 2, 0 to 3, 0 to 4.

(I am using R or python in case this might influence your response)